# Mysqlclient Installation error in python Django

Tags: python, django

I try to build a sample project in Pycharm. But In the step migrate classes i face an error. I am using the code   `python manage.py makemigrations`   Then terminal shows install mysqlclient.  I am using `pip install mysqlclient`  Then shows a error below

```
sreeju@Sreeju:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/SampleProject123$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/SampleProject123/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/SampleProject123/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
(venv) sreeju@Sreeju:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/SampleProject123$ 





(venv) sreeju@Sreeju:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/SampleProject123$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-crybtibd
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  ['8.0.27']
  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lz', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lresolv', '-lm', '-lrt']
  mysql_config --cflags
  ['-I/usr/include/mysql']
  ext_options:
    library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'dl', 'resolv', 'm', 'rt']
    extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
    extra_link_args: []
    include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql']
    extra_objects: []
    define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,0,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.0')]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,1,0,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.0 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:46:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     46 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-tdg7ig2f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/
    Complete output (44 lines):
    mysql_config --version
    ['8.0.27']
    mysql_config --libs
    ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lz', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lresolv', '-lm', '-lrt']
    mysql_config --cflags
    ['-I/usr/include/mysql']
    ext_options:
      library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'dl', 'resolv', 'm', 'rt']
      extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
      extra_link_args: []
      include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql']
      extra_objects: []
      define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,0,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.0')]
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,1,0,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.0 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:46:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       46 | #include "Python.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vlm2hyxh/mysqlclient_8877c17537004f3c9fe9ee8a7dc6c4d4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-tdg7ig2f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sreeju/PycharmProjects/pythonProject21/venv/include/site/python3.9/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try `pip install mysql-connector-python`. It does not require any C libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlclient` is not a Python library, it's a binary, which should be installed using your OS package management software.

For Ubuntu the command will be like `sudo apt-get install <package_name>`, for Mac you can use `brew` etc.

Also, besides the MySQL client you'll need a MySQL database software installed and configures (user/database created).

Comment: How can i install MYSQL database software in ubuntu?

Comment: @Sreeju a there are tons of tutorials on this topic, I guess you should google for it and choose what you'd like the most.